# in_array based if/then/else statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Im looking to create a conditional within an in_array statement.  Basically, I would like to have a value (within div tags) returned for every key within an array which is outputted by Wordpress. In essence, Wordpress outputs keys from this array based on a checkbox dialog in the admin backend.  So, if a key within the array is not found (because the administrator did not click it on in the checkbox within the backend), than it will simply wont display it at all.

Here is the closest code I can ascertain as being what is needed.  I decided that for testing purposes, I would temporarily have the words "Nope" returned if a key within the array is not there (rather than "simply not displaying it" as mentioned in the paragraph above).

```
$my_arr = get_custom_field('product_options');
$opts = array(
'Option 1' => '<div>Option 1 description</div>',
'Option 2' => '<div>Option 2 description</div>',
'Option 3' => '<div>Option 3 description</div>',
);

foreach($opts as $k=>$v) {
if (in_array($my_arr[$k],$opts)!==TRUE)  echo $v; else echo 'nope'; 
}
?>
```

The above code has been tested and it does dispaly "Option __ description" for everything. It even displays "Option 2 description" when Option is not actually being outputted within the array (based off of the admin not clicking Option 2 within the backend). This is not correct and I wish to get it to (in this case for ease of testing) the echo within the "else" part of the above statement.

**Update 2: Current code is here: http://codepad.org/nxzFUMMn**

**Update: Current code is here: http://codepad.org/iXVbmLGL**

Comment: What does `$my_arr` look like?

Comment: @tandu I did an var_export on $my_arr.  Also, please note the Update 2 in the original post as the code has changed.  I am almost there!

var_export outputs: array ( 0 => 'Option 1', 1 => 'Option 3', )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here was to switch the arrays around, e.g.

```
<?php
$my_arr = get_custom_field('othermulti');

$opts = array(
    'Man' => '<div>Man description</div>',
    'Bear' => '<div>Bear description</div>',
    'Pig' => '<div>Pig description</div>',
);

$opts_arr = array_keys($opts);

if ( is_array($my_arr) ) {
    foreach($opts_arr as $opt) {
       if ( in_array($opt, $my_arr) ) {
          print $opts[$opt]; // will print the description for checked items.
       }
       else {
         print $opt . ' was not checked.';
       }
    }
}
else {
    print 'No options checked.';
}
?>
```

**get_custom_field()** is a custom template function for the plugin where this was used.  See the following link for the details:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ifelse-statement-for-custom-checkbox?replies=16

Answer (score 0):

What is happening indicates that in fact none of the values of `$my_arr` match a value of `$opts`.  I think you want to use

```
if (in_array($my_arr[$k], array_keys($opts)) !== TRUE) {
```

Also note that `$my_arr[$k]` === `$v` and `in_array($x, $y) !== TRUE` === `!in_array($x, $y)`

Comment: Okay.  Tried it as you suggested but still no result:

    `$my_arr = get_custom_field('product_options');`
    `$opts = array(`
   `'Option 1' => '<div>Option 1 description</div>',`
    `'Option 2' => '<div>Option 2 description</div>',`
    `'Option 3' => '<div>Option 3 description</div>',`
    `);`
 
    `foreach($opts as $k=>$v) {`
    `if (in_array($my_arr[$k], array_keys($opts)) !== TRUE) echo $v; else echo 'nope';`
   ` }`
    `?>`

Comment: You need to answer what `$my_arr` looks like to truly be helped

Comment: See code I just pasted.  Again, $my_arr is a Wordpress request of "get_custom_field('product_options'); "

Comment: @cwallenpoole  Well, opts is also given to equal an array. `$opts = array (`

Comment: I don't know what "a Wordpress request of `get_custom_field()`" means.

Comment: @Mary I just noticed that there was a missing `)`. Tandu wrote the answer.

Comment: @Tandu Where is the missing  )?

Comment: get_custom_field relates to Custom Content Fields in Wordpress (from the Custom Content Type Manager plugin).  I created a custom field named 'product options.  Within that field, I add different items which go into the array.   `get_custom_field('product_options')` outputs in array format.

Comment: @tandu Can you repost the code as it should be including fixing the `)`

Comment: @mary, no what is literally the result of `var_dump($my_arr);`?

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Option 1" [1]=> string(8) "Option 2" [2]=> string(8) "Option 3" } `

Comment: The keys of `$opts` and `$my_arr` do not match.  Instead of `$my_arr[$k]` you actually need to use `$my_arr[$v]`

Comment: Code is getting some headway, albiet 2 flaws: http://codepad.org/nxzFUMMn

Flaw 1: div tag content still does not show up after a break (`<br>`>.  I might need to figure out how to pass that value back but this code seems to lack the $k=>$v thing.  

Flaw 2: Still am not getting "nope" to show up for custom field valuess unchecked in admin backend.  Instead, nothing shows up.

Flaw 3: With the above code, I get an error if the admin has a product entry with no options checked "on".  Error reads: **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**